# How to fix error related to 'speedtest' module in windows?

Tags: python, windows, speed-test

I am trying to use the `speedtest` module to test the download/upload speed using Windows and use the following code:

```
import speedtest
st = speedtest.Speedtest()
st.download()
```

However, I get some extensive error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DALEX\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\speedtest.py", line 1493, in get_best_server
    fastest = sorted(results.keys())[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "J:\Tools\Local\stest.py", line 5, in <module>
    st.download()
  File "C:\Users\DALEX\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\speedtest.py", line 1518, in download
    (os.path.dirname(self.best['url']), size, size))
  File "C:\Users\DALEX\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\speedtest.py", line 1112, in best
    self.get_best_server()
  File "C:\Users\DALEX\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\speedtest.py", line 1495, in get_best_server
    raise SpeedtestBestServerFailure('Unable to connect to servers to '
speedtest.SpeedtestBestServerFailure: Unable to connect to servers to test latency.
PS J:\Tools\Local> python .\stest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DALEX\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\speedtest.py", line 1493, in get_best_server
    fastest = sorted(results.keys())[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "J:\Tools\Local\stest.py", line 5, in <module>
    st.download()
  File "C:\Users\DALEX\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\speedtest.py", line 1518, in download
    (os.path.dirname(self.best['url']), size, size))
  File "C:\Users\DALEX\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\speedtest.py", line 1112, in best
    self.get_best_server()
  File "C:\Users\DALEX\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\speedtest.py", line 1495, in get_best_server
    raise SpeedtestBestServerFailure('Unable to connect to servers to '
speedtest.SpeedtestBestServerFailure: Unable
to connect to servers to test latency.
```

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: If an index of zero is out of range, the list is empty. As it says, it's failing to find any servers. You seem to have skipped some of the steps related to servers shown by [the examples](https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/wiki).

Comment: Ah examples! Did not find them. Thanks

Comment: @jonrsharpe I seem to have to select a server. So what servers can I choose from? Where can I see a list? Any server? When I run speedtest on the webpage I also do not need to select a server.